# Excel “External table is not in the expected format.”

Tags: c#, excel, exception

I have already read several posts answering to this issue, but none of them worked for me.

The file is an 2013 Excel Workbook, but what is weird is that a few hours ago it was reading the file completelly fine but suddenly it stopped working. I thought that maybe the file got corrupted, so I tried with a new file but is still not working.

Tryed with a new project but is the same, here is a part of the code(The exception is being thrown when I open the new connection)

```
        OleDbCommand oleExcelCommand = default(OleDbCommand);
        OleDbDataReader oleExcelReader = default(OleDbDataReader);
        OleDbConnection oleExcelConnection = default(OleDbConnection);
        sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+FilePath+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";
        oleExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
        oleExcelConnection.Open();
```

Comment: Ran into the same issue weeks ago and we moved to using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`